# JQuery cycle, thumbnail src rotator on hover with fadeIn

Tags: jquery, rotation, thumbnails, fadein

Any chance to add fade In effect with this function, is use function below to rotate thumbs on my site

example http://jsfiddle.net/u6PLS/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var timer,
      count = 0,
      cycle = function(el){
        var s = el.attr('src'),
         root = s.substring( 0, s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 );
        count = (count+1)%4;
        el.attr('src', root + ((count==0) ? 'default' : count) + '.jpg');
     };

     $('.img').hover(function(){
       var $this = $(this);
       cycle($this);
       timer = setInterval(function(){ cycle($this); }, 800);
     }, function(){
       clearInterval(timer);
     });

    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this fiddle work?
**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/jEqrN/1/ 
**JS:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
 var timer,
  count = 0,
  cycle = function(el){
      var s = el.attr('src'),
      root = s.substring( 0, s.lastIndexOf('/') + 1 );
      count = (count+1)%4;
      var url = root + ((count==0) ? 'default' : count) + '.jpg',
          overlay = $('<img src="'+url+'" class="imgoverlay" style="height:'+el.height()+'px;width:'+el.width()+'px;"/>');
      el.before(overlay);
      el.fadeOut(300,function(){
          overlay.remove();
          el.attr('src',url).show();
      });
 };

 $('.img').hover(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   cycle($this);
   timer = setInterval(function(){ cycle($this); }, 800);
 }, function(){
   clearInterval(timer);
 });

});
```

**CSS**:

```
.imgoverlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.img{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Yes but problem is because first image have fadeOut that white background than fadeIn new image, i mean maybe is better to have just fadeIn with new image so i will have effect like one image over another but with fade

Comment: Well then to accomplish that you'll need to elements ontop of each other